# How to make php script to run insert sql Query and then get information from the inserted rows ? I am a Beginner

Tags: php, mysql, insert, fetch, echo

I have so far this script and I am aiming to run the sql insert query and fetch the results and echo some of them to appear in the web page. I want to have id and code and Period to appear in the output. Everytime, I run the script, it gives me the error message ' 0 results ' even though I checked through phpmyadmin that the query was successful and a new row was inserted as I hoped.

I copied some parts of this code from different forms, I doubt that my success key "if ($result->num_rows) {" with insert sql are not a match. Could someone help me with how to define correct success key for the insert query and help me to output the ID and CODE and PERIOD from the inserted data. Thank you very much

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypass";
$dbname = "xtream_iptvpro";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$randnum = rand(1111111111111111,9999999999999999);
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO codes (id,code,period,userid,statut,prixcode,ip) VALUES (null,'$randnum',365,73,0,0,'$ipaddress')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['id']."  ".$row['code']."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You must perform a `SELECT` query to get data from the database. An `INSERT` does not return anything.

Comment: Or use mysqli::$insert_id to get the autoincrement id value.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `$result =` setting, because an `INSERT` will not return the results of what records it added.  You must do a `SELECT` for this.  I'm also going to fix your code to use prepared statements.  Change this part of your code to simply...

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO codes (code,period,userid,statut,prixcode,ip) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
$sql->bind_param('iiiiis', $randnum, 365, 73, 0, 0, $ipaddress);
$sql->execute();
```

And then just after this, try setting the result using `mysql_insert_id()` on the connection var and doing a select with a normal, prepared statement.

```
$resultid = $conn->insert_id;

$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM codes WHERE id = ?');
$statement->bind_param('i', $resultid);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
```

`$result` will now hold the results of the newest `INSERT`.  Try doing `print_r($result)` and then adjusting your display-code afterwards to handle that data format.

Comment: @miken32: Good idea, coding without prepared statements just feels wrong, thanks!

Comment: Why do you mix the procedural api with the oop one?